# Compound case for Progress DB

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to do a case statement in an OpenEdge SQL-92 query that can have two columns defining the output.

```
SELECT 
  "PERSON"."First",
  "PERSON"."Last",
  "PERSON"."EmpCode" as EmployeeCode,
  CASE "PERSON"."Building"
     WHEN '111' then 'HQ'
     WHEN '222' then 'OPS'
     WHEN '111' AND "PERSON"."EmpCode" = 'CCLASS' then 'MGMT'
  END as Location
FROM ....
```

The compound case is throwing a syntax error when I run the query.  I know I can do this in MSSQL...  I assume I can for OpenEdge as well?

Any thoughts on how this is accomplished in with OpenEdge SQL?

Proposed based on horse with no name's suggestion:

```
  CASE 
     WHEN "PERSON"."Building" = '111' then 'HQ'
     WHEN "PERSON"."Building" = '222' then 'OPS'
     WHEN "PERSON"."Building" = '111' AND "PERSON"."EmpCode" = 'CCLASS' then 'MGMT'
  END as Location
```

Comment: You can't combine the "short notation" `case` with an `and` condition - not even in SQL Server. The `WHEN '111' AND "PERSON"."EmpCode" ` is not valid in SQL. You need to use a complete expression for all parts `case when "PERSON"."Building" = '111' then .. end`

Comment: Progress 4GL would look something like `FOR EACH Person:`. Is that what you want or do you want a SQL query that will work in Progress?

Comment: That's how much I know about Progress/4GL.  I just found out now that 4GL is a programming language around the query...  I'd like to do this within the query; so I'd assume that's just "progress" then?  I'm not sure I fully understand what you are stating, horse with no name?  I just made an update to my question with the "proposed" query update.  Is that right?

Comment: I just got into the server and tried the "proposed" out and it works.  Thanks, horse with no name.  Much appreciated!  Do you want to answer the question so I can mark is as correct?

Comment: The OpenEdge db supports two query languages/engines -- Progress 4gl and SQL-92.  You are using the SQL-92 engine not the 4gl engine.  (To make it extra confusing there is a SQL-89 subset within the 4gl but no sane person uses that.)